# sessions in php laravel keep resetting with each use

Tags: php, laravel, session

hi guys i have problem with the sessions in php when i try to use them for shopping_cart i explain with codes below

```
class Cart
 {

     public $items;
     public $totalQty=0;
     public $totalPrice=0;

     public function __construct($oldcart)
   {
    if ($oldcart){
        $this->items=$oldcart->items;
        $this->totalQty=$oldcart->totalQty;
        $this->totalPrice=$oldcart->totalPrice;
    }
}

public function add($item , $id){

    $storeditem=['qty'=>0,'price'=>$item->price,'item'=>$item];
    if ($this->items) {
        if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
            $storeditem = $this->items[$id];
        }}
    $storeditem['qty']++;
    $storeditem['price']=$item->price*$storeditem['qty'];
    $this->items[$id]=$storeditem;
    $this->totalQty++;
    $this->totalPrice+=$item->price;
}}
```

this is simple class for adding items into shopping_cart i use it like this

```
public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $product=Product::find($id);
        $oldcart=Session::has('Shopcart')? Session::get('Shopcart'): null;
        $cart=new Cart($oldcart);
        $cart->add($product,$product->id);
        $request->session()->put('Shopcart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('shop.index');
    }
```

with these two part i can add items to session problem is when i try to reach it in front end it give me noting i try to dd here and i can see my data but after i redirect to my shop page

```
<span id="cart-total">{{ Session::has('Shopcart')?  Session::get('Shopcart')->totalQty : ''}}</span>
```

i cant see any thing in here what is the problem i cant see i also add Session class in the controller and the route is ok too

Comment: Firstly, I'll assume that this is all happening on routes defined in `web.php`, since `api.php` routes do not use the session. This being said, sessions can be tricky to diagnose. As a first step open your browser's developer window (for chrome that's opened with F12) and check the session cookie value. If it changes on each request then this means that the cookie is set incorrectly or not at all. You can try changing your session storage mechanism to file or cookie to see if that helps. As I mentioned, session issues can be tricky to debug.

Comment: @apokryfos ty for the answer here is the route i use for this method it has no part in that matter btw Route::get('add-to-cart/{id}', 'ShopingCart@getAddToCart')->name('product.addToCart');

Comment: maybe use of session can help : `use Session;` check this is exactly your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547691/sessions-in-php-laravel-keep-resetting-with-each-use

Comment: @Dilek as i mentioned i already add the use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session

Comment: Your answer and your working function is in that question `Session::save();`

Comment: @Dilek mate that link u shared is my question

Comment: @mehran I wanna say something if you dont mind. I dont think you cant make it work proper way, issues with that tutorial is all over on internet from 4 years ago since now,  You are not using routes properly, showing some code from `cart.php` and some from `productController.php` wont help you to solve issues, even if you solve this next will start. why ? because that classes and routes entents to each other, trying to change 1 value will efect to all your script, that classes using

Comment: `namespace` to route and `use App\Cart;
use App\Product;
use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;
use Auth;
use Stripe\Charge;
use Stripe\Stripe;` using tons of arrays. Final: download a fresh new instal and edit it to your requirements, without changing credentials, Ask new question if you need with total codes and complete classes. Goodluck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer duo to help of @apokryfos the default driver of laravels above 5.2 are cookie  all i  need was change it to file to do the trick duo i dont know how to set cookies like this if u found some doc about this please share with me

Comment: Cookies have a size limit of 4kb so you might have hit that limit if you're storing a lot of things in the session.